# android change textview outside of TabWidget within an activity

Tags: android, textview, android-tabhost, tabactivity, tabwidget

I have an application with a few tabs which all belong to the same `TabHost`. Is there any way to change the `TextView` `android:text` value before the `TabWidget` in any activity other than the main activity which extends `TabActivity`?

This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/sigma_darkgray">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/title_color"
            android:text="Home page"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="6dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"/>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="1dip"
            android:background="@color/title_color"/>
        <View android:id="@+id/separator" 
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>     
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: You mena you want to change the Value of the TextView from another activity other then the MainActivity ?? right ??

Comment: I want to change the `text` value of the `TextView` from a child activity, not the `TabActivity` that has content: main.xml.

Comment: Yes, any other than the main activity.

Comment: Please refer my answer and if you dont get answer then let me know.

Comment: Have you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes You can.
Just give the id to the TextView. And Declare reference of that textview in MainActivity where there ie TabActivity is Extended.

Now in another child activity You can call that textView with the MainActivity.textview object.

Now here you cna change the TextValue of the textView and it is done from child activity.

Enjoy.

Comment: I think you mean make a method in the main activity `public void changeTextView(String newText)` and define the `TextView _myTitle` in the Main Activity class, right?

Comment: U can make method for it or if dont want to make mathod then also you can change the text directly.

Answer (score 2):

In the activity started from the TabHost

```
((MyParentActivity)getParent()).setYourText("whatever")
```

where you must create the "setYourText(String text)" method.

Comment: I would have accepted your answer if you were a few minutes faster, both answers are the same, thanks anyway!

Comment: How do you fetch the parent activity following his advice? Also, I don't think it's a good practice to access another Activity's field directly through "MyActivity.textviewReference". It may confuse newcomers that follow his answer. Anyway, glad you got your problem fixed.